# Convert dataframe of pandas to array by Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe, plotly

I would like to convert data in specific column of dataframe to keep in new array. For bring the value in each array to plot a graph by [Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly). But result of my code isn't work.

My dataframe look like this(sample) :

```
>> df
        col1                      col2
0     2.5837    07-08-2018 05:46:20 AM
1     1.9394    07-08-2018 19:14:55 AM
2     2.9940    08-08-2018 12:00:40 AM
3     3.4684    09-08-2018 09:31:02 AM
```

I try use this code : `xScale = df["col2"].values` and `yScale = df["col1"].values`

This is result of code that I try convert dataframe to array :

```
>> xScale 
         ['07-08-2018 05:46:20 AM' '07-08-2018 19:14:55 AM' 
          '08-08-2018 12:00:40 AM' '09-08-2018 09:31:02 AM']
>> yScale 
         [2.5837 1.9394 2.9940 3.4684]
```

This is I want a new array **xScale(str)** , **yScale(float)** :

```
xScale = ['07-08-2018 05:46:20 AM', '07-08-2018 19:14:55 AM', 
          '08-08-2018 12:00:40 AM', '09-08-2018 09:31:02 AM']
yScale = [2.5837, 1.9394, 2.9940, 3.4684]
```

And this is my **Plotly** of **xScale** and **yScale** : 
[image]
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it's work!!! :  `xScale = df["col2"].tolist()` and `yScale = df["col1"].tolist()`